# when trigger gesture cancel state?

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer

The Apple doc says that

A recognizer for a continuous gesture can also transition from Changed to Canceled (UIGestureRecognizerStateCancelled) if it decides that the gesture no longer fits the expected pattern.

I want to know when a recognizer will be cancel state.for example, there's a rotate gesture in my view, if I left one finger, the gesture is still in changed state, why it is not in cancel state?

Comment: can you answer the question and I will accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cancel is reserved for instance where the system cancels the gesture (for example, a UIAlertView is shown while the gesture is active, or the user double taps the home button to show the recently used apps list).